# How to pass parameters into xml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, resque

I have a job like this: jobs/create_site_map.rb

```
    class CreateSiteMap
      @queue = :create_site_map
      def self.perform(slct_common_path, http_host, domain_name)
         ... some code ...
        q_jobs = TJob.q_job_site_map(m_site.id)
        q_jobs.each do |job|
        site_map_content =
"\n\t\t<url>
\t\t<loc>#{site_frontsiteurl}index.cfm?fuseaction=job.detail&amp;sgtno=#{job.shigoto_no}</loc>
\t\t<lastmod>#{job.job_dt.strftime("%F")}</lastmod>
\t\t<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
\t\t<priority>0.8</priority>
\t\t</url>\n"
        sitemap_data << site_map_content
      end
     end
   end
```

I want to take "site_map_content" variable above to a .xml file (template) to reuse many times, example :

```
<url>
<loc>#{site_frontsiteurl}index.cfm?fuseaction=job.detail&amp;sgtno=#{job.shigoto_no}</loc>
<lastmod>#{job.job_dt.strftime("%F")}</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

But How to pass parameters into xl file? Pls help me.

Comment: Make it a template, just like erb? Or use a different templating mechanism. Or an XML builder. Or...

Answer (score 3):

Create a template using Erb like this :-

**template = Erb.new(File.read('file_path'))** #this is an yml file

and then pass data into the template:

```
struct = OpenStruct.new(data)

YAML.load template.result(
   struct.instance_eval { binding }
)
```

Later you can convert yml to xml.